# xml javascript getting html attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have an array and this code:

```
console.log(trips_array[0].outerHTML)
```

prints out this:

```
<trip origin="SFIA" destination="FRMT" fare="11.65" origTimeMin="7:47 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016 "
    destTimeMin="9:18 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" clipper="4.35" tripTime="">
  <leg order="1" transfercode="N" origin="SFIA" destination="BALB" origTimeMin="7:47 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016" 
    destTimeMin="8:06 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" line="ROUTE 2" trainHeadStation="PITT" trainIdx="8"/>
  <leg order="2" transfercode="N" origin="BALB" destination="BAYF" origTimeMin="8:13 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016"
    destTimeMin="8:54 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" line="ROUTE 12" trainHeadStation="DUBL" trainIdx="8"/>
</trip>
```

How can I get the value of the attributes? For instance the `trip origin` and the `leg origin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like the following to get the value of the "origin"-attribute of "trip".

```
trips_array[0].getAttribute("origin");
```

You can get the "origin"-value for the first leg-element like that:

```
trips_array[0].children[0].getAttribute("origin")
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how I could get all the leg attributes? So basically what is the best way to iterate thru the legs to get the attrs.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar something like
`for (var i = 0;i<trips_array[0].children.length;i++) {
trips_array[0].children[i].getAttribute("origin"); //Your value
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use getElementsByTagName and getAttribute like below.

```
//  That returns an array
var trips = document.getElementsByTagName('trip');

trips[0].getAttribute("origin");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the values of the attributes would involve using jQuery. Thus, you have two options:

1. Get all the origins, irrespective of whether they belong to trip elements or to leg elements. In that case, the solution is:

   console.log($("trip, trip leg").attr("origin"));
2. Get the origins of the trip and leg elements separately. In that case, the solution is:

   console.log($("trip").attr("origin"));

   console.log($("trip leg").attr("origin"));

The latter solution is more verbose, but it is more helpful if, instead of logging the attributes to the console, you want to save them in variables.